# Search with ajax for multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search

Here is some example code for one if the search field and it is a select box

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is HTMl code for input field

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

This two ajax related form's are working individually..

What i want is those two opertions should take place in single form and single ajax script

can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like -

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str,type)
{
    var str2 = '';
    if (type == 1)
    {
        if (str.length==0 && document.getElementById('users').value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;         
        } else {
            str2 = document.getElementById('users').value;
        }
    } else {
        if (str.length==0 && document.getElementById('text').value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;         
        } else {
            str2 = document.getElementById('text').value;
        }
    }

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str+'&str2 = '+str2,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" id = "text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value,'1');">
<select name="users" id = 'users' onchange="showHint(this.value','2');">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: u havnt initialise str2 in function()